# Rescaling axis changes properties of map

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, dynamical-systems

Suppose I have a map $T:[-1,1]\to [-1,1]$. If I want to view this as a map from $[0,1]\to [0,1]$, I change my cooridnates such that $\bar{x}=(x+1)/2$ and let $\bar{T}(\bar{x})=(T(\bar{x})+1)/2$. Will the maps $T$ and $\bar{T}$ have the same properties? Certainly they will have the same number of fixed points but they will just be translated. Is studying $\bar{T}$ equivalent to studying the map $T$? Is there possibly a reference which describes the relationship between these maps?

Comment: Yes, any two closed intervals are Homeomorphic. And translation of a map through Homeomorphism preserves all the topological properties.

Comment: This depends on the property.  NewB is correct that they will have the same topological properties. They will also share most interesting analytical properties too. But obviously they differ in some properties. Domain, codomain, and image are properties of a map.